# failed to parse xml: Unrecognized property 'com.ctc.wstx.maxEntityCount'

Tags: xml, fasterxml, woodstox

I'm using `'com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.5.0'` dependency to work with `XMLInputFactory` via `WstxInputFactory` In a gradle project. When I try to run the below code,

```java
xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
xmlInputFactory.setProperty(WstxInputProperties.P_MAX_ENTITY_COUNT, 100000);
```

I'm getting `failed to parse xml: Unrecognized property 'com.ctc.wstx.maxEntityCount'`

I have included the woodstox dependency in my `build.gradle`(`implementation 'com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.5.0'`).

I have debugged my code and verified that `xmlInputFactory` instance is a `WstxInputFactory` instance.

I also tried excluding `com.codehaus.woodstox` like below to make sure this is not an issue of transitive dependency conflict since `P_MAX_ENTITY_COUNT` is not available in `com.codehaus.woodstox` versions.

```
configurations.implementation {
    exclude group: 'org.codehaus.woodstox', module: 'woodstox-core-asl'
}
```

It would be much appreciated if anyone can help with this. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since this property was added in Woodstox 4.2, I would try to double-check that there is no possibility of an older version being present in classpath during deployment: compilation succeeding with String constant getting compiled in, but `WstxInputFactory` coming from an older jar.